# what is the difference between the commands "clear" and "reset"?

Tags: bash

what is the difference between the commands "clear" and "reset" ?

(the whole question is in the title, but the website refuse to let me make a post without a body, hence the duplicate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`man clear`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/clear.1.html) and [`man reset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/reset.1.html) explain what each command does in detail.

`clear` *only* clears the screen (including the scroll-back buffer, if possible), and it only outputs the terminal sequences to do so to standard output. Other settings aren’t touched, so for example if the background colour is set, `clear` will fill the terminal with that colour:

```
tput setab 2; clear; echo test
```

`reset` fully resets the terminal: it restores various modes to their expected values, resets the window size, resets delays and tab expansions, outputs the terminal’s [“reset” or “initialisation” sequence](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html), and flushes the output. It tries various inputs and outputs to determine how to talk to your terminal, instead of blindly using standard output; this ensures that it will have an effect on your terminal. It also waits to give the terminal time to reset. Thus

```
tput setab 2; reset; echo test
```

will always result in a cleared terminal with default settings (white on black in most default setups).

If you try both you’ll see that `clear` is instantaneous, whereas `reset` takes a little over a second (because it explicitly sleeps for a second, in the hope that that will be enough for whatever terminal is in use to reset).

Comment: `reset` waits because it explicitly calls `sleep()` to wait until the terminal has "settled" (lol), not because it takes a lot of time to do all that stuff

Comment: Yes @UncleBilly, as I wrote, “It also waits to give the terminal time to reset.”

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. But does that make any sense? A real hw terminal may take longer than 1 second to reset itself, while a pty + terminal emulator doesn't need any timeout at all. My impression is that `reset` (as everything terminal-related) simply strives to be as obtuse and anachronistic as possible ;-)

Comment: Yup, it’s stuck between two worlds, one of which is long gone in practice...

Answer (score 1):

```
NAME
       clear - clear the terminal screen

SYNOPSIS
       clear [-Ttype] [-V] [-x]

DESCRIPTION
       clear  clears your screen if this is possible, including its scrollback
       buffer (if the extended “E3” capability is defined).   clear  looks  in
       the environment for the terminal type given by the environment variable
       TERM, and then in the terminfo database to determine how to  clear  the
       screen.

       clear  writes  to  the  standard output.  You can redirect the standard
       output to a file (which  prevents  clear  from  actually  clearing  the
       screen),  and  later  cat  the  file to the screen, clearing it at that
       point.
```

```
NAME
       tset, reset - terminal initialization

SYNOPSIS
       tset [-IQVcqrsw] [-] [-e ch] [-i ch] [-k ch] [-m mapping] [terminal]
       reset [-IQVcqrsw] [-] [-e ch] [-i ch] [-k ch] [-m mapping] [terminal]

   reset - reinitialization
       When invoked as reset, tset sets the terminal modes to “sane” values:

       •   sets cooked and echo modes,
       •   turns off cbreak and raw modes,
       •   turns on newline translation and
       •   resets any unset special characters to their default values

       before doing the terminal initialization described above.  Also, rather
       than  using  the  terminal initialization strings, it uses the terminal
       reset strings.

       The reset command is useful after a program dies leaving a terminal  in
       an abnormal state.
```

The first clears the screen, including the scrollback buffer. On top of that the second one resets input and output. `reset` is also kind of slow.